# Unable to compile Delphi 7 flatStyle component

Tags: delphi, compilation, components

I am trying to compile a project on Delphi 7, it uses SDLsuite, TeeChart8.06 and flatstyle.
All of them third party components.

When I attempt to install flatstyle into Delphi, I can't compile and I get this error.

[image: Error]

I can't figure out where this error is coming from and I've googled and tried with different flatstyle packages but this problem is always the same.

I tried with a clean Delphi installation, still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TColorProperty` is defined in the unit `VCLEditors.pas` add it to your uses clause.

```
uses VCLEditors, ......
```